# Как узнать время работы системы?

Tags: linux

Интересуют способ, которым можно проверить из терминала, сколько времени работает система после последней перезагрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

командой `uptime`

Примерный вывод:

```
gaal@linux-lybs:~> uptime01:40  up  12:05,  4 пользователя, средняя загруженность: 0,74, 0,81, 0,65gaal@linux-lybs:~>
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще так:

```
$ cat /proc/uptime3475.49 5969.95
```

Первое число показывает, сколько система работает с момента старта в секундах.